# Image from webcam open cv

Tags: python, qt, opencv, pyqt

The program is written for the application and displays the broadcast from the camera video, however, I came across the fact that the output is in some unspecified encoding (format) look photo

```
class Worker1(QThread):
    ImageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    def run(self):
        self.ThreadActive = True
        Capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self.ThreadActive:
            face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml')
            ret, frame = Capture.read()
            if ret:
                image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                with_cascade = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, 1.3, 7)
                for i, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(with_cascade):
                    roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                    r = 300.0 / roi_color.shape[1]
                    dim = (400, int(roi_color.shape[0] * r))
                    resized = cv2.resize(roi_color, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                    w_resized = resized.shape[0]
                    h_resized = resized.shape[1]
                    frame[380:380 + w_resized, 235:235 + h_resized] = resized
                convert_to_qt_format = QImage(frame.data, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.ImageUpdate.emit(convert_to_qt_format)

   
    def image_update_slot(self, Image):
        self.ui.Cam.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(Image))
        self.ui.Cam.setScaledContents(True)
```

How can i fix this problem?

photo with problem:

[image]

Maybe there are problems with the image format, but if I change it, the programme will be closed

Comment: openCV puts color channels in the order BGR, not RGB. that *seems* to be the issue with your picture. -- if that's not what you were asking for, you should clarify.

Comment: Christoph Rackwitz is right. You are converting BGR to RGB: `image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`, but instead if using `image`, you are using `frame`. Replace `roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]` with `roi_color = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]`

Comment: Thank you, i have replace everywhere frame to image.